# Link or button that directs to the current list items version history wihtin an Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, version-history

I need a button or link within the Custom Lists Custom Edit Form that points to the Current List items Version History.

I must be able to do this from SPD 2010?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the version history using following URL format

```
 /_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={list guid}&ID={item id}
```

Replace List GUID and Item ID

Comment: Great...whats the easiest way of getting the GUID and ID in the URL from SPD?

Comment: I believe you can get it from the URL query string.

Comment: And for a document library it's only a little bit trickier. You can't get a library's GUID from the URL query string just by applying a sort or a filter; you'll only get the view's ID, which won't help you. But going to Library Settings will put the library's GUID into the URL query. The easiest way to get the item ID for a document is by adding the ID column to a view of the library.